# Can't install package with source using nuget, any ideas why?

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package

need to debug service stack source and I've found, that they are [publishing their sources](http://www.symbolsource.org/Public/Metadata/NuGet/Project/ServiceStack.Common/3.9.35), but when I run nuget command to install package it fails without any clear exception:

> PM> Install-Package ServiceStack.Common -Source http://nuget.gw.symbolsource.org/Public/NuGet/FeedService.mvc
>   Install-Package : An error occurred while processing this request.
>   At line:1 char:16
>   + Install-Package <<<<  ServiceStack.Common -Source    http://nuget.gw.symbolsource.org/Public/NuGet/FeedService.mvc
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId :       NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand

Never used `-Source` option before, does it work in general? My used version is

> Package Manager Console Host Version 2.2.31210.9045

Comment: Is your NuGet extension up to date?

Comment: To my knowledge - yes, I've included version in question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't managed to solve problem with nuget, but I was able to solve it using workaraound - I've simply added `http://srv.symbolsource.org/pdb/Public` to symbol servers list and it is able to download Service Stack pdb's as I need them.